# How to plot inside a function by generating a counter

Tags: python, function, loops, matplotlib

In the code below I want to see how the `error` changes every time the function is called. However, the plot is a vertical column of points. How can one generate a counter within the function, to provide the x-axis values?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

t = np.random.uniform(0., 100., 100)
y = t**3 - 130*t**2 + 5000*t - 56000 + np.random.normal(0., 10000., 100)

def fn(x):
    a, b, c, d = x;
    fit = a * t **3 + b * t **2 + c * t + d
    error = sum((fit - y)**2)
    plt.plot(error, ".")
    fn.x = x
    return error

init_x = [2, -100, 1000, -10000]
res = minimize(fn, init_x, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
fn(res.x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use a `global` variable as the counter and increment its value each time the `fn` function is called. You can then use that as the x coordinate when using `plt.plot`. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

t = np.random.uniform(0., 100., 100)
y = t**3 - 130*t**2 + 5000*t - 56000 + np.random.normal(0., 10000., 100)

xx = 0

def fn(x):
    global xx
    xx += 1
    a, b, c, d = x;
    fit = a * t **3 + b * t **2 + c * t + d
    error = sum((fit - y)**2)
    plt.plot(xx, error, ".")
    fn.x = x
    return error

init_x = [2, -100, 1000, -10000]
res = minimize(fn, init_x, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
fn(res.x)

plt.gca().set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]